# Creating a custom Pydantic Field to accept "str" or "None" Values

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to create a Pydantic custom field. The main goal of this validator is to be able to accept two data types: "str" and "None". If the value is "None", it should return an empty string. I tried to do it as follows:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class EmptyStringField:
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if v is None:
            return ""
        return str(v)


class Model(BaseModel):
    url: EmptyStringField


model = Model(url=None)
print(model.url)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```bash
url
  none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)
```

Comment: Why just declare the field as `url: str | None`?

Comment: @larsks because I need convert `None` to empty `str`. Unfortunately writing a validator for each model is not an option, I've quite a lot of models. Therefore, the ideal solution for me would be my own custom type with its own validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is for the `url` field to accept `None` as a special case, but save an empty string instead, you should still declare it as a regular `str` type field. You can handle the special case in a custom [`pre=True` validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators). No need for a custom data type there.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Model(BaseModel):
    url: str

    @validator("url", pre=True)
    def none_to_empty(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if v is None:
            return ""
        return v


model = Model(url=None)
print(model.json())  # {"url": ""}
```

---

### Update

If you don't want to repeat the validator in different models for different fields, you can define a catch-all `pre=True` validator on a custom **base model** and implement some sort of logic to discern, which fields on the model to process and how.

One option is to utilize [`typing.Annotated`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) to "package" any given type with some custom conversion function that should be called. The catch-all validator would then check every field for `Annotated` metadata and if it finds a function, it would call that on the value.

Here is a working example:

```py
from typing import Annotated, get_origin

from pydantic import BaseModel as PydanticBaseModel, validator
from pydantic.fields import ModelField


class BaseModel(PydanticBaseModel):
    @validator("*", pre=True)
    def process_annotated(cls, v: object, field: ModelField) -> object:
        if get_origin(field.annotation) is not Annotated:
            return v
        func = field.annotation.__metadata__[0]
        if not callable(func):
            return v
        return func(v)


StrOrNone = Annotated[str, lambda v: "" if v is None else v]


class Model1(BaseModel):
    url: StrOrNone


print(Model1(url=None).json())  # {"url": ""}
```

Comment: Yes, this is an option, but the problem is that this validator will need to be added to each model, and in some places it may not be a URL, but a title, etc.

Comment: @elektruver Should this be shared behavior for _all_ `str` type fields for all those models? Or should there still be `str` type fields that _do not_ allow this `None`-special casing?

Comment: I'd not like to do this for all `str` fields. I would like to create something like my own data type with own validator that can accept `str` or `None` and in case `None` it should convert to empty `str`

Comment: @elektruver Unfortunately, Pydantic (at least v1) treats `None` very inconsistently from all other values. There is a separate "switch" of sorts for every model field telling it whether or not to accept `None` as a value. And this check is done before your custom data type validators are called. So this is not possible to do, purely with a custom type as far as I can tell.

Comment: @elektruver I added a possible workaround. Instead of actually creating a custom type you would just define an `Annotated` type alias and add whatever conversion logic you want to it in the form of a function.